# How to json_encode stock data from mysql using php

Tags: php, json

Hi i am creating a stock app in php and using highcharts (highstock), i have mysql data and know how to json_encode but i would like to encode and get results as seen in this link https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

i have done something like this:

```
$sqlgetresults = $db->query("SELECT * FROM STOCK");
    $datas = array();
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlgetresults))
    {
        $datas = $data;
    }
    $datas= json_encode($datas);
    echo $datas;
```

Comment: `$datas[] = $data;`

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
    $out = array_values($datas);
    json_encode($out);
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but how do i loop so that i can get the ([ [id1,data1],[id2,data2]])

Comment: Try using foreach over $out.